# If loop isn't checking the condition and not filtering the data right

Tags: angular, typescript, if-statement

```
 this.authService.getmonthsandyear(this.id).subscribe(data => {   
  this.authService.startdate(this.id).subscribe(start_date_data => { 
    for (let a of data) { 
        // if ( a.month !== start_date_data[0].month && a.year !== start_date_data[0].year)  { OR
     if ( a.year && a.month  !== start_date_data[0].month && start_date_data[0].year !== a.year) {
        this.authService.getmonthwiseyear(a.month, a.year, this.id).subscribe(data ={ 
          this.month.push((this.theMonths[Number(a.month - 1)]));
          this.month.push(a.year);  } else {}
```

The above code's if loop isn't performing else loop for the same month year condition in the commented if loop template all the month's belonging to the year = start date year are getting filtered instead of only month of the year that matches start month year [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gQKF6.png)

Comment: your code is difficult to understand and probably you did some errors, please add some parenthesis (). What do you wanna do? `(a.year && a.month)  !== start_date_data[0].month` or maybe `a.year && (a.month  !== start_date_data[0].month)` or something else???
also what are `a.year and a.month`? two numbers? if you do `2022 && 11` the result is 11

Comment: What i want to check is 
for instance my start month and year is '3 2018' and 
current data i have is [ '3 2018','4 2018', '5 2018',.............,'5 2020']
i want the if loop to ignore '3 2018' and send the remaining to the router

Comment: still not very clear what `a.year` and `a.month` is, but I assume those are numbers.
 and what is `start_date_data[0].month`? a number or a string?

Comment: a.year = 2018
a.month = 4
start_date_data[0].month  = 3
start_date_data[0].year = 2018

Comment: please check the image attached

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your problem, this should be the solution

```
if (a.month !== start_date_data[0].month || start_date_data[0].year !== a.year) {
  // it's not the same date
}
else{
 // it's the same date 
}
```

if this dosen't work try to debug your code with some logs:

```
const differentMonth = a.month !== start_date_data[0].month;
const differentYear = a.year !== start_date_data[0].year;
console.log('different month:', differentMonth);
console.log('different year:', differentYear);
console.log('different month or year:', differentMonth || differentYear);
```